# Select distinct id with max date according to department

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table such as following

```
RevNo | RevContent          | PIC      | Created
-------------------------------------------------------
 00   | Testing Purpose     | Smith   | 2008-01-11
 01   | Testing Purpose     | Windsor | 2008-02-01
 02   | Test                | Thorn   | 2008-01-05
 02   | Testing             | Baker   | 2008-03-01
 03   | Testing only        | Sykes   | 2008-01-20
```

I want the output like below, it display the latest date for each rev no. and other details

```
RevNo | RevContent          | PIC      | Created
----------------------------------------------------
 00   | Testing Purpose     | Windsor | 2008-02-11
 01   | Testing             | Baker   | 2008-03-01
 02   | Testing only        | Sykes   | 2008-01-20
```

But when I run the sql, it display the value with the latest date only like below, I want it display the latest date for each rev no. and it based on department(session).

```
RevNo | RevContent          | PIC      | Created
----------------------------------------------------
 01   | Testing             | Baker   | 2008-03-01
```

My query:

```
SELECT CCSMASTERLISTREVNO, CCSREVCONTENT, CCSPREPAREDREV, CCSREVEFFECTIVEDATE
FROM CCS2_TBL_MASTERLIST a 
WHERE CCSEQUIPMENTDPMT = :DPMT AND CCSREVEFFECTIVEDATE = 
 (
SELECT MAX(CCSREVEFFECTIVEDATE) FROM CCS2_TBL_MASTERLIST 
 GROUP BY CCSMASTERLISTREVNO HAVING CCSMASTERLISTREVNO =a.CCSMASTERLISTREVNO
  ) 
ORDER BY CCSMASTERLISTREVNO DESC
```

Comment: why Testing Purpose     | Windsor | 2008-02-01 whit revno 00  .. in your desired result ?  the revno 00 is not the latest date related  version ..

Comment: @KaushikNayak, I just checked the edit history and it doesn't look like I did change the data, only the formatting.

Comment: @jmcilhinney : Ok, then it seems N.I.A : You should edit your expected o/p to answer  scaisEdge's question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use `row_number()`

```
SELECT RevNo
    ,RevContent
    ,PIC
    ,Created
FROM (
    SELECT t.*
        ,row_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY RevNo ORDER BY Created DESC
            ) AS rn
    FROM t
    )
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Another is to use the `LAST` aggregate function.

```
SELECT RevNo
    ,MAX(RevContent) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY CREATED ) as RevContent
    ,MAX(PIC) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY CREATED ) as PIC
    ,MAX(Created) as CREATED
FROM t
GROUP BY RevNo;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery group by each department (CCSMASTERLISTREVNO) but the HAVING clause is wrong. Instead you should use compound columns in an `IN` clause. Something like this:

```
SELECT CCSMASTERLISTREVNO
       , CCSREVCONTENT
       , CCSPREPAREDREV
       , CCSREVEFFECTIVEDATE
FROM CCS2_TBL_MASTERLIST a 
WHERE CCSEQUIPMENTDPMT = :DPMT 
AND (CCSMASTERLISTREVNO, CCSREVEFFECTIVEDATE) in 
 (
     SELECT CCSMASTERLISTREVNO, MAX(CCSREVEFFECTIVEDATE) 
     FROM CCS2_TBL_MASTERLIST 
     GROUP BY CCSMASTERLISTREVNO )
  ) 
ORDER BY CCSMASTERLISTREVNO DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

I didn't really understand your question but maybe this can help you.

```
SELECT RevNo, RevContent, PIC, MAX(Created) as Created
FROM your_table_name 
GROUP BY RevNo
ORDER BY Created DESC
```

I think you need first Group your entries by the RevNo and then you sort by taking the Last Created of each group.

Comment: That is an invalid use of `group by`